# Is there any reason to FK a PK column to itself

Tags: oracle, database-schema

I'm trying to understand whether the situation best described in SQL below is a WTF or a hack of some sort:

```
alter table CORE_FIELD 
add constraint R_106 foreign key (CO_FIELD_ID) 
references CORE_FIELD (CO_FIELD_ID) on delete set null;
```

Database: Oracle 11.2.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of anything meaningful that would be accomplished by such a constraint.  Obviously the constraint would always be satisfied so it does not serve an integrity function.  I had a thought that maybe it was a hacky way of preventing deletions, but it doesn't do that in my experiments.

Comment: My thinking was that it might have been an attempt to get an UPDATE trigger to fire when the row was deleted, but I did a little testing and found that no UPDATE triggers (either BEFORE or AFTER) were fired when a row was deleted. (Makes sense, but you never know until you try :-).